# Material3 lateral animation for image carousel

Tags: flutter, material-ui, material-design, flutter-animation

Is it possible to use the lateral animation from the material3 documentation using flutter (for example with a PageView)?
I am mainly interested in the effect that the image adjusts to the size of the page when swiping horizontally.

[material3 lateral animation](https://m3.material.io/styles/motion/transitions/transition-patterns#2774e205-1632-492b-941c-f7f962e88916)

Answer (score 0):

Flutter uses material3 natively so yes- it works precisely like the example in the link. Images are adjusted however you tell them to adjust eg. if they have a fixed size they will stay in that size.

Image behavior with lateral animation is shown on the same page- [here](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/design-spec/o/projects%2Fm3%2Fimages%2Fl79a328i-15%20-%20Lateral%20-%20Photo%20Album%20-%203P.mp4?alt=media&token=4a69b6c5-9bf6-442b-9cd1-958cf0bdf4f0)

Comment: exactly the linked example I mean. Do you know how I get this effect that the content of the images is adjusted to the scroll position? When I use a normal PageView it always keeps the width when scrolling

Comment: I'd start by working with TabBarView class to add animations to elements directly. You can find more information here: https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-tabbar-tabbarview-examples